# How to get each item in array without foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have an array that i store some values read from csv file. I can successfully read the csv file.

What I need is to use elements in array (like echo username ) without using a loop like foreach or for. I just need to get single value from an array without using any loops.

**Update**

my array is something like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => base
            [1] => accounts@oakmaninns.co.uk
            [2] => Attleborough
            [3] => Oakman Inns & Restaurants
            [4] => GB
            [5] => 
            [6] => James
            [7] => Collins
            [8] => 
            [9] => NR17 1YE
            [10] => 
            [11] => Norfolk
            [12] => 0
            [13] => c/o LT Management Services Ltd 31 Haverscroft Ind Est New Road
            [14] => 
            [15] => 01953 450054
            [16] => 
            [17] => 1
            [18] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Ok good luck. Tell us if you succeed

Comment: `echo $array[random_int(0, count($array))];` gives you a single value without any loops :)

Comment: Ok so we have no idea how your array looks like, why you can't use foreach, what you want as output and you show no try...good luck?

Comment: So to get the country in your data above target the index you need e.g.: `echo $data[0][4];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use array functions with anonymous functions to do something like an echo.  But usually a foreach loop will do, and likely will be easier to read:

```
<?php

$peeps = [
    [
        'name' => 'Foo',
        'age' => 23
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Bar',
        'age' => 47
    ]
];

array_walk($peeps, function($v) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $v['name'] , ', Age: ' . $v['age'], "\n";
});
```

Output:

```
Name: Foo, Age: 23
Name: Bar, Age: 47
```

Compare that with:

```
foreach($peeps as $v)
    echo 'Name: ' . $v['name'] , ', Age: ' . $v['age'], "\n";
```

Output:

```
Name: Foo, Age: 23
Name: Bar, Age: 47
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is an option to use [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php), for example:

```
$arrays = [
    [
        "base",
        "accounts@oakmaninns.co.uk"
    ]
];
list($var1, $var2) = $arrays[0];

echo $var1;
echo $var2;
```